# Somatic Mutations in meristem tissue in plants

Tags: evolution, botany, plant-physiology, mutations, plant-anatomy

In angiosperm, **in which layer of the meristem does a new mitotic mutation occurring has chance to be found in a pollen grain or in an ovule?**

I also welcome some insights about non-angiosperm plants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the wikipedia article on meristem.

The apical meristem differentiates into floral meristem that gives rise to flowers.
From this the cells specifically expressing *APETALA3 (AP3), PISTILLATA (PI), AGAMOUS (AG) and SEPALLATA (SEP)* would give rise to the stamen [<sup>[ref]</sup>](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168952507002715).

CRC gene is essential for female development and plants lacking this will not produce pistils. So cells expressing this gene will give rise to female parts[<sup>[ref]</sup>](http://www.plantphysiol.org/content/150/4/1764.full).

Nonetheless mutation happening at any stage of the development of floral meristem can be transmitted to the pollens/ovules if the mutated cells stochastically give rise to that lineage.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know approximatively, how many cells are in the apical meristem?

Comment: Oh I don't have much idea. I didn't study much botany. I'll look up and let you know..